# Make and open linux directory with one commmand

Tags: linux, command-line, shortcuts, cd, mkdir

Instead of doing:

```
mkdir build
cd build
```

or:

```
mv build build_2017_03_03
cd build_2017_03_03
```

What is one command that does both?

Answer (score 4):

There's no built-in command that does this, but you can create a shell function that does it, like this: `mdcd () { mkdir -- "$1"; cd -- "$1"; }` You can change `mdcd` to any name you want. You can create an analogous function for `mv` + `cd` as well.

Comment: With some improvements: `mdcd () { mkdir -p -- "$1" && cd -- "$1"; }`

Comment: @KamilMaciorowski I agree with the `--`, but I'm not sure how I feel about an implicit `-p`.